# Is there anyway to assign a global variable after declaration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, logic, global-variables

Is there any way to assign a variable before you do a global declaration of that variable? I understand this exists to avoid the problems that could cause, but why does it raise an error for a function where that wouldn't be a problem? Consider a function that looks like this

```
def func():
    if "a" not in globals():
        global a
        a = 0

    else:
        global a
```

I've tried to make this logically impossible to declare a `global a`, and have `a = 0` in `locals()`. Because the first time the functioned is called, it declares `global a` and then assigns it a global value. For all calls after that `a` shouldn't be in `locals()`, so why still raise a syntax error?

I understand that I could simply move `global a` out in front of the `if` loop to fix the syntax error, but is there any way to keep `global a` in the `else` loop without raising a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-global_stmt

> Names listed in a global statement must not be used in the same code block textually preceding that global statement.

“Textually preceding...” sounds like an explicit language against the thing you are attempting.